# how to delete a variable programmatically in a notebook from another notebook

Tags: programming, notebooks, variable, expression-test, editing

**how to delete a variable programmatically in a notebook from another notebook?**

```
c = b;
```

I have already tried `Remove[c]` but `Remove` deletes the value. i want to delete variable c like it is no longer displayed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to delete a cell in notebook A containing `c = b` using an expression in notebook B?

Comment: thanks for the comment. yes i'm trying to delete a variable in a cell in notebook A using an expression in notebook B.